# Hyperref and hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref

With the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{en.wikipedia.org}{\emph{gungumapu}}
\href{en.wikipedia.org}{gungumapu}
\end{document}
```

I would expect "gungumapu" to appear in `emph` (italic) typeface and in plain upright typeface, both times with a link under it, i.e. if I click on either appearance of "gungumapu", I'd expect `en.wikipedia.org` to open in my browser. Only that doesn't happen. Why is that? Is my expectation wrong? If so, how do I put a hyperlink in my document?

Comment: `en.wikipedia.org` is not a URL: `http://en.wikipedia.org` works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The protocol is missing. `\href` tries to detect different protocols (URL links, file links, links to PDF files, ...). As egreg has written in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/192139/hyperref-and-hyperlinks#comment443373_192139), specifying the correct, complete URL helps:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/}{\emph{gungumapu}}
\href{http://en.wikipedia.org/}{gungumapu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK. This solves the problem in the given MWE. The actual problem was with `\href{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_{n\%3D1}^{infinity}\%28arctan\%282\%2F\%28n^2\%29\%29\%29}{\emph{questo}}`. In this case, `http://` is there, but still the link won't open, even removing the \ from `\%` at each appearance in the URL. What do I do with this?

Comment: @MickG: The URL is correctly written into the PDF file. It seems there is a bug in firefox. If I directly use the URL in firefox, then its get scrambled (no parentheses, ...). The URL in chromium or opera works.

Comment: OK, but on my Mac `http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_1^infinity+arctan(2/n^2)` works in Firefox and gives the same problem as the other one with `\href{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_1^infinity+arctan(2/n^2)}{questo}`.

Comment: Same problem with `\href{http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_1^infinity+arctan\%282\%2Fn^2\%29}{questo}`: working URL in Firefox, but no URL in the pdf.

Comment: @MickG: Tested with `xpdf`, works fine. If you are using the Acrobat plugin, that is AFAIK also buggy. Test with different PDF viewers/browsers.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek: If you are using pdfTeX, then set `\pdfobjcompresslevel=0`. Then you can inspect the PDF file (text/hex viewer/editor). The URL is stored as PDF string between parentheses, look for `/URI(...)`. If the URL is correct, then the problem lies elsewhere (PDF viewer, browser, ...).

Comment: I tried that. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_1^infinity+1%2Fn^2%29 turns to http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum_1^infinity\0401/n^2), with that confusing \040, but http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1/x^2 is perfectly fine, yet neither opens.

Comment: @MickG: `\040` is the octal notation for a byte in a PDF string, use `%20` instead. Try a [URL shortening](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL_shortening) service to get a better URL, which works with buggy programs.

Comment: Yep, bitly worked. So I guess both TeXShop and Preview are sort of buggy when it comes to PDF URLS, right?

Answer (score 2):

What's your question here?  You say that "that doesn't happen," but don't tell us which:  the italic and plain upright typeface, or the opening of the link in your browser?

If the latter, then Heiko's answer (from the package developer, no less!) covers your issue.

If the former, then you've got bigger problems.  :-)  The two links appear in italic and upright, but they are surrounded with the default colored box to indicate that they're links.  If this is what bothers you, you can control the appearance of links with options that you pass to hyperref.  If you do:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
```

You'll get colored text instead of the boxes.  You can choose which color the links are with linkcolor:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

Or, since your links are to URLs and not internal:

```
\usepackage[colorlinks,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
```

The hyperref manual is excellent and gives more information about this.